# Change image using hover over link with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, hover, settimeout

I am designing a mega menu and wanted to update image inside a div according to the link being hovered upon. What I am trying to do is put a wait for the **mouseleave** part of the code so that if the user moves instantly to the next **LI** tag, the **mouseleave** part of the code is not executed. But if the user does not **mouseenter** another **LI** for 2 seconds, then this **mouseleave** code is executed.

The problem is that #1 returns the value alright, but #2 gives an 'undefined' value. Why is that and how can I fix that? How can I fetch the attr of the current LI being hovered INSIDE the setTimeout function? Since once I have the value, I can do a comparison to control the flow. Thanks a lot.

```
// FADE IN THE IMAGE ACCORDING TO THE MENU ITEM
// HTML=<li><a data-pos="left -256px" href="somelink">Link A</a></li>
var $sprite = $('#photo');

    $('li>a').hover(
        function() {
            sprite_pos=$(this).attr('data-pos');        // fetch value for the tag
            // Put an if otherwise this code gets executes for all li>a creating an unnecessary fade-in out effect
            if(typeof(sprite_pos)  != "undefined") {
                $sprite.fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                $sprite.css("background-position",sprite_pos); });
                $sprite.fadeTo(200, 1);
            }
        },
        function() {

            //sprite_pos=$(this).attr('data-pos');          // #1

            setTimeout( function() {
                sprite_pos=$(this).attr('data-pos');        // #2 fetch value for the tag

            if(typeof(sprite_pos)  != "undefined" ) {
                $sprite.fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
                $sprite.css("background-position",default_pos); });
                $sprite.fadeTo(200, 1);
            }   // if(typeof(sprite_pos)  != "und ...
            }, 2000 );
        }

    );  // $('li>a').hover( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When `setTimeout` is called `this` becomes the `window` object. To fix simply create a reference to the original `this` context:

```
function() {

    var me = this;

    setTimeout( function() {

        sprite_pos=$(me).attr('data-pos');        // #2 fetch value for the tag
        ///          ^^

        /// ... rest of code
```